# what is the value of $a+b?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Can anyone help me to solve this problem:
$x$ and$y$ are real numbers which satisfy $x>y$ and $xy<0$. If
$\left | x \right | + \left | y \right | + \left | 42y-x \right | + \left | 23x-y \right |$
can be expressed as $ax+by$, what is the value of $a+b?$

Answer (score 3):

since $x>y,xy<0\Longrightarrow x>0,y<0$,
so
$$42y-x<0, 23x-y>0$$
$$|x|+|y|+|42y-x|+|23x-y|=x-y-(42y-x)+23x-y=x-y-42y+x+23x-y=25x-44y$$
so
$$a=25,b=-44,\Longrightarrow a+b=-19$$